# OSX Cocoa: Error in resetting colors in two drawRect method implementations

Tags: macos, cocoa, drawrect, nscolor

I have a Table subclass of NSView which contains several blocks of the Block subclass of NSView. This is the code for Table's drawRect: method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [[[NSColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6] set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:dirtyRect];
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

And this the code of Block's drawRect: method:

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [color set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:dirtyRect];
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

where "color" is set to [[NSColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0].

But I don't understand why, when I run the application, evenrything's fine, but each time I click on a Block this gets filled with the classic gray initial background on Mac OS X... can anybody help? I would be very greatful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Block's drawRect call to "`colorWithAlphaComponent`" to "`1.0`" and I think you'll be all set.

An alpha of zero means a transparent opacity.  Check out [Apple's "Color Programming Topics" document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/UsingColorSpaces.html) and you'll see them mentioning "alpha" a few times.

p.s. you may want to change the class name of "Block", since it might confuse people who are thinking of traditional Objective C blocks ^ { }.

Comment: Yes but I wanted it to be transparent because I originally wanted to add a gradient in Table's background... when I tried to do this, though, every time I'd click on a Block it would add the gradient to its background, and I don't understand why.. Hope you can help

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Michael, could you help me with my drawRect problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855349/how-to-make-2-contradictory-methods-work-in-drawrect